# How to debug an OrderItem in flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, debugging

**Context**

I am on a Sandbox environment.

I’ve created a flow that is triggered when a OrderItem is Created or Updated.

To be sure that it runs smoothly, I wish to use the debug function, with the following pop-up.

---

[image]

---

I have no other options for Path for Debug Run (1 ).

**Problem**

My problem comes from  the fact that I can’t choose an OrderItemto debug with (2).

I know that for certain object, such as Orders, I need to put the name of the Order, but I don’t have any with the Order Item (or am I mistaken ?).

**What I’ve tried**

Even if I knew that the chances were slim, I tried with the OrderItem Id. No luck.

I tried modifying an OrderItem on an Order, hoping it would trigger something. Nothing happen.

Have you encountered the same difficulty ? Do you a solution to my (seemingly easy) problem ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue(W-9305713) from salesforce. You need to create a custom compact layout and add the required fields and order product number and make that compact layout for the users. Now you can debug the order line flow with order product number as shown below.

Compact Layout:

[image]

OrderLine flow Debug:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a million for your kind help ! It has done the trick